# Installing package not found in conda

Tags: python, conda, python-twitter

I'm using python 3.6 as anaconda, and im trying to install `python-twitter` package, but there is no package compatible from conda manager. How can i download the package outside conda manager in order to use it later with jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can install `pip` in your **conda env** and then run `pip install python-twitter`.

It should work.

Answer (score 13):

```
Ubuntu:/$ which pip
/home/superadmin/anaconda2/bin/pip
Ubuntu:/$ /home/superadmin/anaconda2/bin/pip install apache-beam
```

It worked...

Answer (score 10):

If you prefer conda packages over pip where possible, check other channels first with:

```
conda install [--channel | -c] conda-forge
```

Search multiple channels:

```
conda search -c bioconda -c conda-forge
```

Add a channel to the default search (see [docs](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html) for managing precedence order):

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

Some of the popular channels are listed in [Explanation of different conda channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42309333/explanation-of-different-conda-channels)