# Install sklearn_pandas with conda via Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, scikit-learn, conda, sklearn-pandas

I'd like to install the [sklearn_pandas](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/sklearn-pandas) library with conda via the Windows command line. The package is apparently "private" on the conda repository (admittedly this may well be why I cannot install it, but I prefer to ask for advice just in case there is a way around this).

I have tried `conda install -c creditx sklearn_pandas`, but get the following error:

```
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current cha
nnels:

  - sklearn_pandas

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/creditx/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/creditx/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Anyone know how I might install the package with conda (not pip as specified in the package README)?

Comment: I can see a public package [here](https://anaconda.org/creditx/sklearn_pandas) with install instructions, but its an outdated version.  Why dont you want to [install `sklearn_pandas` with `pip` inside your anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009966/installing-package-not-found-in-conda) environment?

Comment: Thanks for your useful response! I wasn't aware you could install packages in the Anaconda environment with pip. That seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use, `easy_install <package_name>`, in your case:

```
easy_install sklearn_pandas
```

[Easy Install](https://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/branches/setuptools-0.6/EasyInstall.txt) is a python module (`easy_install`) bundled with `setuptools`
that lets you automatically download, build, install, and manage Python
packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can install `sklearn-pandas` using:

```
pip install sklearn-pandas
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd install `sklearn-pandas`, like this:

```
pip install sklearn-pandas
```

If you're using `python3` you'd run this:

```
pip3 install sklearn-pandas
```

And if you need to use `sudo`, you'd run this:

```
sudo -H pip3 install sklearn-pandas
```