# Necesscity of pip inside conda environment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

When Anaconda installed, additional packages can be installed in the environments using `conda install` command. But I see people using `pip` command inside an activated environment created/managed by conda.

Are there any reasons why it becomes necessary to use `pip` when we have Anaconda installed already?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44009966/6394617) answer your question? Or [this](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages) from the conda docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common reason I know of for using pip while already in a conda environment is because anaconda.org does not have the package. It is rare for Anaconda to not have a package that pip does have but I've encountered it before. In general though, avoid using pip whenever you can. Installing from pip can be dangerous because it doesn't check for conflicts between the package and other packages already in your environment, whereas the conda installation process does.

Side note: If you like conda, I would recommend switching to [mamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) or micromamba (if you want something lighter on the system) and setting the default installation channel to condaforge - this is all explained on the website. It just makes managing environments more enjoyable than regular conda (or pip). For example, it makes pretty colours in the terminal and installs libraries in parallel, so it's really fast.

Comment: Hi @Turbulent Flow, thanks for your great & crystal clear explanation! I will try to use mamba as you suggest. thanks again!