# What are the differences between two methods- 'conda install anaconda' and 'conda install conda-forge' to install a package through conda?

Tags: anaconda, conda

One method of installing a package through conda is-

```sh
conda install -c anaconda lxml
```

And another is-

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge lxml
```

What are the differences between these two?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explanation of different conda channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42309333/explanation-of-different-conda-channels)

Comment: Have you checked the Conda documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `conda install -c` or  `conda install --channel` context, `anaconda` and `conda-forge` are CHANNELs to two different package repositories.

1. `anaconda` repo is managed by Anaconda, Inc. (https://anaconda.org/), and
2. `conda-forge` repo is managed through community effort. (See https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html for more info).